# Set a variable in Test Class - Laravel 5.5 Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit

I init this variable in Test class Laravel 5.5

```
public $token;
```

In testA() I set this variable

```
$this->token = "xxx";
```

I need to get the value of this varibale in testB(), but when I get, it return null.

How can I get the value os this varibale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need a class variable. You can just run testA and return the token from there. Then you run testB with the `@depends`-notation and pass in the value from testA as a parameter. See [phpunit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.examples.StackTest2.php) for more details.